# Using React navigation 4.xx to 6.0

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-navigation, navigateurl

```js
import {NavigationActions, StackActions} from 'react-navigation';

const action = StackActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    actions: [
        NavigationActions.navigate({
            routeName: 'Applied',
            action: NavigationActions.navigate({
                routeName: 'Belod',
                params: {count:23},
            }),
        }),
    ],
});
return navigation.dispatch(action);
```

I am using this with "react-navigation": "^4.4.3" But I have updated it to 6.x.x so getting an error as this module is not found. So how can I move the StackActions code to the latest react-navigation. please check and update it.  Thanks

Comment: You  can uninstall the app, remove the package-lock.json and put npm install react-navigation -- save, after that npm install and run again the app

Comment: @CodeLover but i have to remove it react-navigation. As i have to use 6.0.0

Comment: You can install it like npm install react-navigation@6.0.0